# probabely "loop" and "output" doesn't work properly in my bash script

Tags: linux, bash, loops, awk, nmap

I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Reading data - headers - both"

if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Usage: ./nmap <port-range> <ip-list> <d || h || b>"
    exit 1
fi

rm -f /tmp/right.txt 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
rm -f /tmp/wrong.txt 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null

output=""
if [ $3 == h ]; then
    while read -r -u3 port; do
    while read -r -u4 ip; do
#       echo -en "\n$ip $port: "
        OUT=$( nmap -p "$port" --script=http-headers.nse "$ip" | awk 'NR>=7 && NR<=10')
     #   [[ $OUT == *Apache* ]] && $(echo -en "$ip  $port\n" >> /tmp/right.txt) || $(echo -en "$ip  $port\n" >> /tmp/wrong.txt)
        [[ $OUT == *Apache* ]] && output="$output `echo -en "\n$ip -------------------- $port "`" && echo -e "$output" | column -t >> /tmp/right.txt || output="$output `echo -en "\n$ip -------------------- $port "`" && echo -e "$output" | column -t >> /tmp/wrong.txt
    done 4< "$2"
    done 3< "$1"

    echo -e "$output" | column -t

elif [ $3 == d ]; then
    echo data
elif [ $3 == b ]; then 
    echo both
fi
```

I expect my output  have two files:

```
cat right.txt
ip1 ..... port1
ip2 ..... port1
ip2 ..... port2
ip3 ..... port3
.
.
.

cat wrong.txt
ip1 ..... port1
ip2 ..... port1
ip2 ..... port2
ip3 ..... port3
.
.
.
```

but it doesn't work properly...

any idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would edit my post and put my real output

Comment: Try `[[ $OUT == *Apache* ]] && output="$output `echo -en "\n$ip -------------------- $port "`" && echo -e "$output" | column -t > tee /tmp/right.txt /tmp/wrong.txt > /dev/null`

Comment: @ JKB pardon..I would try it..but I would also so thankful if you edit my script amd modify it in answer part...

Comment: i have updated your scripts is it working for you?

Comment: @ JKB I am going to check

Comment: @ JKB the output just show me the correct result...but right.txt and wrong.txt are empty..the std output just show me the right output

Comment: ok you get correct result on stdout but not get that in file right? check my updated script

Comment: @ JKB we are closing step by step...at the stdout i have just right output...and both right and wrong.txt i have right output...

Comment: ok, please check your script again i have again modified it..it will done your job.

Comment: please add in end of inner while loop `echo -e "$output" | column -t | tee /tmp/right.txt /tmp/wrong.txt >> /dev/null` it will works for you

Comment: @JKB I am really thankful but the result is exactly the same as original post....pardon..please put your answer in answer part to get upvote or accept if needed..

Comment: `rm -f /tmp/right.txt 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` this is incorrect.  You should probably remove the redirections altogether, or replace with a simple `: >/tmp/right.txt` which will fail if you do not have write access to this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please find updated answer as i modified the BMW's answer for you please check it.

```
   #!/bin/bash

    echo "Reading data - headers - both"

    if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
        echo "Usage: ./nmap <port-range> <ip-list> <d || h || b>"
        exit 1
    fi

    join -j 2 $2 $1 > temp.txt

    headers() 
    {
         while read -r ip port
         do
            printf "ip: %s  port:%d \n" $ip $port
            OUT=$(nmap -p "$port" --script=http-headers.nse "$ip" | tac | awk -F: 'NR<=13&&/Apache/{print $2; exit}')   
            if [[ "$OUT" == *Apache* ]]; then
                echo $ip $port >> /tmp/right.txt
            else
                echo $ip $port >> /tmp/wrong.txt
            fi
         done < temp.txt
    } 

    case $3 in 
      "h") headers ;;
      "d") echo data;;
      "b") echo both;;
      "*") echo "wrong input"
           exit;;
    esac
```

Comment: @ JKB we are really close but the right and wrong are still not correct :(

Comment: @MortezaLSC can you give out put of my newly edited answer..i edite just second ago

Comment: @ JKB I put the output in answerpart.see please

Comment: @MortezaLSC above script working for me..also updated output in my answer

Comment: @ JKB as you see your output repeated...why?..I am going to show you my real ideal output...(I checked your answer doesn't work :( ..I am really thankful)

Comment: yes it's repeated,only checked for one ip so it as.

Comment: @ JKB I put in original post my ideal answer... :( ... I am really thankful my friend

Comment: see this link and answer of BMW..may be good (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597450/search-in-output-and-cat-from-specific-line-to-specific-line-and-search-again)

Comment: @MortezaLSC welcome my friend..it's great you find your answer and i also tried my best to solve it but anyway thanks..

Comment: @ JKB you're welcome...If we can solve it in this way it is better to do what BMW said...but If find the best solution I would be thankful again.. :)

Comment: @ JKB you see that link has some problems...but this way I think is better if we could solve it

Comment: yes i see that..but from BMW answer `join` command not working and i test your solution from my side and it works for me why you get web address instead of ip address still it mystery.

Comment: @ JKB ok .. my work is just with ip..but even when i put your last edited answer in answer part it also does't chek the `condition` correctly :(

Comment: @MortezaLSC i can't get you which `condition` are you pointing?

Comment: @MortezaLSC please find my modified BMW's answer.

Comment: @ JBK excellent dear friend :)... so sweet ... I changed (--script=http-headers.nse "$ip" | tac | awk -F: 'NR<=13&&/Apache/{print $2; exit}')) to (--script=http-headers.nse "$ip" | awk 'NR>=7 && NR<=10')) and worked exactly what I want..thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your short-circuit logic is flawed.  `true && false || true && true` will execute all four statements.

It's not clear why you think the output status of `echo` would indicate anything except success anyway.

Is this closer to what you mean?

```
output="$output `echo -en "\n$ip -------------------- $port "`"

[[ $OUT == *Apache* ]] && file=/tmp/right.txt || file=/tmp/wrong.txt

echo -e "$output" | column -t >>"$file"
```

This is still wrong because it will echo the accumulated `output` multiple times, but at least it should show you what needs to be changed (and also how to refactor your code to avoid repetitions).

I guess you actually want something like

```
[[ $OUT == *Apache* ]] && file=/tmp/right.txt || file=/tmp/wrong.txt
output="$output `echo -en "\n$ip -------------------- $port " | tee -a "$file"`"
```

except this doesn't run the copy in the file through `column -t`.  But you can do that later, or add it here and avoid it later (you seem to be running it for all instances of the output in the end anyway).

Comment: can you modify my script..I didn't understand sorry